# If statement along with Swing not working as expected, how to put EDT to sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a `JTextField` named `tf`. A user is supposed to enter his name in the field. I also have a `Jbutton` named `p` and I have written the below code in such a manner that `p's` `actionListener` should only run if the user has entered something in the text field. But the code inside the `if statement` runs even if nothing is entered in the text field that is null.

```
    while(true)
    {
        if(tf.getText()!=null)
        {
    p.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)


    {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");
        ne.remove(p);

    }
    });
    break;
    }
    }
```

Why is the program not running as expected?
Is it something related to threads?

Is there any means by which I can put EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) to sleep?

Comment: Is it possible `tf.getText()` is returning `""` and not `null`?

Comment: @BrandonLaidig Is it not supposed to return `null` by default..if nothing is entered?

Comment: @BrandonLaidig setting `if(tf.getText()!="")` gives the same result.

Comment: @MathewsMathai if(tf.getText()!="") you should use string.equals

Comment: Also, you should put a breakpoint on the `if (!tf.getText().equals(""))` and then check the value of `tf.getText()`. That will give you an indication of what might be happening

Comment: @ControlAltDel  `if(tf.getText().equals(null)==false)` and `if(tf.getText().equals("null")==false)` both are giving the same result as above.

Comment: Why the `...==false` ?

Comment: @BrandonLaidig I already used `System.out.println(tf.getText());` to check the value returned by `tf.getText();` and it prints "   " .

Comment: Yeah, so that means it's returning an empty string value, not null. So the following should do what you need, `if (!tf.getText().equals(""))`

Comment: @BrandonLaidig it's working now. Changed `==false` to `!=false` .

Comment: What do you mean "put the EDT to sleep?".  If the problem is, the user hasn't entered any text into the field, then how will "putting the EDT to sleep" fix that?  If any event handler fails to return, then the user will not be _able_ to enter any text into the field.  If an event handler fails to return, the user won't be able to do _anything_;  Menus won't work, buttons won't work, text fields won't work, windows will fail to re-draw, and the Operating System likely will report that the application is "failing to respond."  Users always recognize that behavior as "crashed" or "locked-up."

Comment: @jameslarge like other threads, I would like to know if I will be able to put EDT to sleep for a time period or not.

Comment: The usual thing to do, if there's some control that you don't want the user to operate when the text field is not valid, is to write a handler that fires each time the contents of the field changes.  The handler should disable the control whenever the content becomes invalid, and it should re-enable the control whenever the content becomes valid.  Extra credit for providing a tool-tip that tells the user _why_ the control is disabled.

Comment: I don't get it.  You mean you want some _other_ thread to suspend the EDT?--It's always a bad idea for one thread to suspend another--or do you mean you want an event handler to call `Thread.sleep()`?  Either way, it's a bad idea for the EDT to be blocked for any amount of time for the reasons that I described above.

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks a lot for the tip. I will take a look at controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment, this should fix your issue

```
while(true) {
    if(null != tf.getText() && !tf.getText().equals("")) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

As a side note, when dealing with values like this, I tend to check for both null and empty to cover all bases

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when the value is not set in case of a `string` ,it should ideally return `null`. right?

Comment: You'd have to check the javadoc to be sure, but yes, I think so. I can update my answer to account for both cases

Comment: That would be better for future reference. Please update so that I could accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: What about putting EDT to sleep? Any clue?

Comment: @MathewsMathai You shouldn't put EDT to sleep. If you need to know more, you can start a new question since this question is solved.

Comment: @user3437460 Well, that particular question would lack codes and would result in an inappropriate question in SO. That is the reason I commented it.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.getText()` will never return `Null`, so you can easily check the length if it is greater than `0`.

```
if(tf.getText().length() > 0) {
   // do the stuff
}
```

Comment: I think if `tf.getText()` does return null that you'll get a NullPointerException for trying to access the `.length()` method

Comment: Sorry this will not return Null.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a likely scenario, but if it were to somehow get set to null, then you'd have a problem. i.e `tf.setText(value)` where `value` was somehow set to null

Comment: If you carefully read the source you will see that will never return Null, even if you setText(Null).

Comment: This is what I'm seeing in the javadoc for JTextComponent which JTextField inherits. [JTextComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText())

Comment: Look to this man! and then vote down other's answer: `tf.setText(null);
        System.out.println(tf.getText() == null); // false` Now you will accept that you are wrong right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you edit your post, I can go ahead and remove my downvote